# Lucene Indexing

Tags: lucene

I would like to use Lucene for indexing a table in an existing database. I have been thinking the process is like:

1. Create a 'Field' for every column in the table
2. Store all the Fields
3. 'ANALYZE' all the Fields except for the Field with the primary key
4. Store each row in the table as a Lucene Document.

While most of the columns in this table are small in size, one is huge. This column is also the one containing the bulk of the data on which searches will be performed.

I know Lucene provides an option to not store a Field. I was thinking of two solutions:

1. Store the field regardless of the size and if a hit is found for a search, fetch the appropriate Field from Document
2. Don't store the Field and if a hit is found for a search, query the data base to get the relevant information out

I realize there may not be a one size fits all answer ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For sure, your system will be more responsive if you store everything on Lucene. Stored field does not affect the query time, it will only make the size of your index bigger. And probably not that bigger if it is only a small portion of the rows that have a lot of data. So if the index size is not an issue for your system, I would go with that.

Comment: +1 for Pascal's response. You could also tokenize the large field and *not store* it. This way you can query(search) on the field, get the relevant document/record identifier and retrieve the record from db.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. 
If I opt not to store any Field, I also would not be able to use Highlighting (Lucene contrib module) to highlight search hits?

Comment: It could be done without storing the text, but it is not the easy way. See http://www.lucidimagination.com/search/document/5ea8054ed8348e6f/highlight_arbitrary_text#60f592f5ff0de0c5

Comment: Oups, in my previous comment, I was referring to Solr. With plain Lucene, yes, I think you need to have the field stored.

Comment: And how to get that particular line details to store that info as a field info !

Answer (score 2):

I strongly disagree with a Pascal's answer. Index size can have major impact on search performance. The main reasons are:

- stored fields increase index size. It could be problem with relatively slow I/O system;
- stored fields are all loaded when you load Document in memory. This could be good stress for the GC
- stored fields are likely to impact reader reopen time.

The final answer, of course, it depends. If the original data is already stored somewhere else, it's good practice to retrieve it from original data store.

Comment: Lucene should not be treated as the authoritative source of data. The data should be stored somewhere else anyway so do the keyword based query on a non stored text field then do the look up to get the actual data from the single source of truth.

Comment: Ok. So, How to achieve this ? If any reference link available then it will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

When adding a row from the database to Lucene, you can judge if it actually needed to be write to the inverted-index. If not, you can use Index.NOT to avoid writing too much data to the inverted-index.
Meanwhile, you can judge where a column will be queried by key-value. If not, you needn't use Store.YES to store the data.