# Store fields in database or in Lucene index file

Tags: lucene

My domain object has 20 properties(columns, attributes, whatever you call it) and simple relationships. I want to index 5 properties for full-text search and 3 for sorting. There might be 100,000 records.

To keep my application simple, I want to store the fields in a Lucene index file to avoid introducing a database. Will there be a performance problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239198/lucene-indexing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how you access stored fields, they may **all** be loaded into memory (basically, if you use a [FieldCache](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_0/api/org/apache/lucene/search/FieldCache.html) everything will be cached into memory after the first use). And if you have a gig of storage which is taking up memory, that's a gig less to use for your actual index.

Depending on how much memory you have, this may be a performance enhancement, or a performance detriment.

Comment: Thank you Xodarap.
Then, I think it's better not store them into index.